# Merge Arrays, Sort Value, Remove Duplicates and Reindex

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have two separate Arrays

I want to merge these arrays, however I can't seem to do this.

**Result from F1**

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

**Result from F2**

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

**FINAL RESULT DESIRED**

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 9
        )

)
```

**Note** I am reindexing the Values by numerical order.

Many thanks

Comment: `$ids = array_unique(array_merge($x['id'], $y['id'])); sort($ids); $ids = [ 'id' => $ids ];`. That seems good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without removing the 'id' keys:

```
$newArray = array_merge_recursive($joinedIDs, $committeeIDs);
$newArray = array_map(function($e){return array_unique($e);}, $newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that F1 & F2 were assigning ['ID'].

Removing this, allows the array_merge functions to work as expected.

```
$newArray = array_unique(array_merge_recursive($joinedIDs, $committeeIDs));
```